# Whats the correct list comprehension syntax for this

Tags: python

if I have two lists:

`e = [3,1,5,8]`, `w = [1,2,4]`

and I want to go in and check which element of e is evenly divisible by every element of w, how do I do this in a list comprehension?
so using my two lists, `8` should be returned since `8 % each i in w` will give a zero.

in terms of a for loop I'm thinking of something like:

```
for i in e:
    for j in w:
        if i % j == 0:
            print i
```

but even that is incorrect!

Comment: `[i for i in e if not any(i%j for j in w)]` I guess ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[i for i in e if all(i % j == 0 for j in w)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To check which element of `e` is evenly divisible by every element of `w`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fractions
import functools

e = [3,1,5,8]; w = [1,2,4]
lcm = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a*b // fractions.gcd(a, b), w)
result = [i for i in e if i % lcm == 0]
# -> [8]
```

This is linear algorithm (if numbers are limited) unlike the nested list comprehension that is quadratic algorithm e.g., if `e`, `w` were to contain a million numbers each then the linear algorithm would require around a million operations that should be fast even on modest device, at the same time the quadratic algorithm would take ~1e12 (a number with 12 zeros) operations that may take a while.

---

In general, if you see:

```
L = []
for i in e:
    for j in w:
        if i % j == 0:
             L.append(i)
```

then it is equivalent to:

```
L = [i for i in e for j in w if i % j == 0]
```

i.e., all you need is to remove colons and add brackets -- the order is exactly the same.

If you need to figure out the correct syntax for a list comprehension then it means that you should probably leave the code as the explicit nested loops.

Comment: will this always give the same result as your answer


    `e = [1,3,5,8]
    w = [1,2,4]
    L = [i for i in e for j in w if i%j == 0]
    r = []
    q = max(set(L), key=L.count)
    for i in w:
        if q % i == 0:
            r.append(q)
    if len(r) == len(w):
        print q`

Comment: @FakeBrain: no, the code in the second part of the answer just shows the syntax—it is not meant to produce the same result as the first part with lcm. Use the lcm code, to check for divisibility. The list comprehension is equivalent to the code with explicit nested loop from your question that does not check for divisibility correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If a number is evenly divisible by every element in a list of numbers then it also has to be evenly divisible with the product of all the numbers in the list.

```
e = [3,1,5,8, 16, 32]
w = [1,2,4]


product = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, w)

answer = [i for i in e if i % product == 0]

# print answer  ->  [8, 16, 32]
```

Comment: It is incorrect. Imagine 4 were in `e`; your code would exclude it. You want `lcm = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b/fractions.gcd(a, b), w)` instead.

Comment: Ouch your right this happens when the largest number is a multiple all the other numbers in the list.

Comment: no, it happens for any sequence of numbers that are not relatively prime i.e., if `gcd(a,b) != 1`